# Manipulating CSS styles of pseudo elements in Firebug

Tags: css, firebug, pseudo-element

Is is possible to manipulate CSS of pseudo element `:before` or `:after` using Firebug? I know these are specific elements that are handled internally by browsers but Firebug has more low level access (I suppose) so maybe it has the ability to manipulate these as well.

Comment: This is the corresponding firebug-ticket as far as I know http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=537

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeing CSS pseudo-elements in Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417656/seeing-css-pseudo-elements-in-firebug)

Comment: @tazotodua: This specific question is older than the one you're offering as a possible duplicate. So your duplicate should rather be the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit a stylesheet in the CSS tab and

- add new rules for pseudo-elements
- alter existing pseudo-element rules

However, I can't find any pseudo-element styles in the computed styles panel. Probably because the styles don't apply to the elements but rather their contained pseudo-elements. Neither can I find a way to inspect pseudo-elements using Firebug.

Comment: I've looked into this as well, and with the current firebug isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

The firefox bug causing this problem is now solved, so pseudo-element (such as ::before and ::after) should show up in the firebug 'style side bar'. It doesn't work in all cases though, but it seems to work in most of them.

You can read more about the firefo bug causing the problem here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=557726

Answer (score -1):

You should click the parent TAG,and then you will see its :after/:before classes in right side:

[image]