# Seeing CSS pseudo-elements in Firebug

Tags: css, firebug, pseudo-element

Is there any workaround to see CSS pseudo-elements like `:after`, `:before`, etc. (which are known as [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/)) in Firebug?

Right now, when I select an element, I only see static CSS applied to it. I don't see styles applied to it using `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements.

Comment: strange, i don't have any problems seeing those elements...

Comment: I don't have any problems either. In firebug, I see the element, then below that I see the :before, and :after psudo's.

Comment: Generally single colon (:) is used for pseudo-classes like :first-child, or :hover, while for pseudo-elements you should use double colon (::) like ::before and ::after.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185431

Answer (score 1):

You can use webkit's (chrome) developer's tool to view and modify pseudo-element's style, while you won't be able to inspect them via HTML, you can select the affected elements which generates the pseudo-element and you will see the relevant CSS.

Answer (score 1):

click directly onto parent TAGNAME to see its **::after** **::before** classes:

[image]